# "Are you happy?" as a greeting

Tags: traduction

I was speaking with a French-Canadian person recently, and he mentioned that there's a French greeting that translates to "Are you happy?" I thought this was interesting because it strikes me as a pretty profound question when asked in English - or at least, certainly not a lighthearted greeting.

I've been trying to figure out what the exact phrase is in French (I have no way of contacting this person anymore), but I haven't been able to find anything. The closest I've come is "Tu vas bien?" which strikes me more as "Are things going well?" than "Are you happy?"

Was there a misunderstanding here? Or is there really a common French (or French-Canadian) greeting that translates like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a common one but there is a French expression that can be used a jocular way to greet someone:

> ***Alors, heureux ?***

It translates to "So, are you happy ?" and possibly "So, did you enjoy it ?"

While this phrase is technically not that different from the mainstream ***ça va ?***, it can't really be used without a context and implies familiarity between the parties involved. It might be ironical too, toward someone that has reasons not to be happy.

It is the masculine variant of the well known catchphrase

> *[**Alors, heureuse ?**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alors,_heureuse_%3F)*

which is mocking the kind of question a macho lover might ask to his partner after doing it.

Comment: Would you say that "Alors, heureux?" could be used without context? Like, when there's nothing specifically implied to be happy about / enjoy?

Comment: It can't. Answer updated.

Comment: You can say that only in the context of an event that involves the person talked to in the way of ending in gratification for that person.

Comment: Et que dirais-tu de « Ça boume ? » variante souriante et familière du banal « ça va ? ». À moins que ce soit vraiment passé de mode ou encore une question de génération...

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer because it does present a valid explanation for how "Are you happy?" might be used as a greeting. However, I'm not convinced that this is what the person from my original question was referencing. I think I must've just misheard him, as it sounds like there is no normal way to greet someone with "Are you happy?" without context.

Comment: @Laure L'expression n'est pas encore trop démodée mais n'est pas très proche de *are you happy*. Elle est en revanche plus utilisable quel que soit le contexte qu'*alors, heureux*. Je ne vois pas ce que ça pourrait être d'autre.

Comment: Cameron Sun, my reply is more about European French. There might be a better answer from French Canadians when they show up here.

Comment: @sinopleincandescent Oui, *ravi* pourrait coller mais s'applique à la personne qui parle (*ravi de vous rencontrer, de vous connaître, de faire votre connaissance*), pas au destinataire (*êtes-vous ravi ??*)

Comment: Absolument. Je pense qu'il y a sans doute encore plus de confusion et qu'on ne saura jamais vraiment. L'interlocuteur aurait du indiquer de quoi il voulait parler. La question confirme que l'équivalent anglais d'un groupe de mots français ne sert absolument à rien et ne permet pas à l'apprenant d'apprendre quoi que ce soit sur la langue.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "Alors, ça va comme tu veux?", or "Ca roule?".
Both questions have a slight problem, in that they could be suggesting a current problem or task that both parties agree on. If not it's life in general, that is being referred to.

Answer (score 0):

Your being at a loss for a usable translation, at least in metropolitan French, seems to reflects reality : I'm afraid there is no such formula. There are a few formulas that you might use with people  that life has recently treated badly or people who are depressed and  as far as inquiring about someone's state of mind by way of a greeting, it's the closest  to what is concerned by the question.

- Comment va le moral ? *also* • Comment ça va le moral ?
  (*Apparently, "How is the morale?" is not used in English ([ref.1](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/comment-%C3%A7a-va-le-moral.1697281/), [ref2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=How+is+the+morale%3F&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)). In that language it seems that "How have you been feeling lately?" is what comes closest. (see the first ref.))*
- Comment vous sentez-vous aujourd'hui? (English : *How are you feeling today?*)

You use the first question  to show that you are wondering whether the person you're  talking to is in fairly high spirits. They are not under an obligation to answer and they may reply with their own greeting; if you think it important to have an answer, you may  politely reiterate the question. Even though it is used as explained above it can also be used in a lighthearted way for greeting anybody you know well enough. This is not true of the second, which is specific to situations referred to in the introduction; this second formula will in fact be often preceded by another greeting and be more of a real question than a greeting.

I don't know about Canadian French, there might be a possibility in that variant of French.